# Moment.js HTTP Server result is not currently outputting correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, momentjs

First time using javascript and Momentjs library. I have an issue with the output as it is not printing what is needed. I need to output dates in the format "Day, date month year"(e.g. Tuesday, 14th May 2018). I need to use a loop to go over the empty array `dates` that then outputs a formatted version of each date on its own line, and need to do this in the `createServer` function.

I am using code sandbox and very confused as to why this isn't working.

I've looked on moment.js and other forums but none answer my problem.

```
var http = require("http");
var moment = require("moment");
moment().format();

function getDates(start, end, dates) {
  var start = moment.isDate(new Date("1st Jan 2019"));
  var end = moment.isDate(new Date("31st December 2019"));
  var dates = [];
  var current = start.clone();

  if (current !== moment.isoWeekday(1)) {
    current = moment().add(1, "w");
  }
  while (current.isBefore(end)) {
    current.clone.push(dates);
    current = moment.add(2, "w");
  }

  return dates;
}

http
  .createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
    res.write("day,date", "\n");
    var dates = function getDates() {};
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
      moment.res.write.format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY", "\n");
    }
    res.end();
  })
  .listen(8080);
```

What happens is that it only displays `day, date` on the output screen. And I need formatted dates of which I tried to produce from the empty array variable 'dates' which is defined in the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dates = function getDates() {};
```

doesn't call the `getDates()` function. It makes `dates` the name of a new function that doesn't do anything, similar to writing

```
function dates() {
}
```

Change that to:

```
var dates = getDates();
```

Another wrong line is:

```
  moment.res.write.format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY", "\n");
```

That should be:

```
res.write(moment.format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYYY", dates[i]), "\n");
```

You can't combine `res.write` and `moment.format` into a single function call. And you need to format the current element of the `dates` array.

Comment: I changed this before but then after doesn't print anything. Code sandbox just goes straight to a bug: '502 bad gateway'.

Comment: You're not using `dates[i]` in the `for` loop.

Comment: This line makes no sense: `moment.res.write.format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY", "\n");`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I thought I had done that the right way. The initial problem is still there though. Once I changed the first line you stated to 'var dates =  getDates( );' the same bug appeared and didn't print out anything

Comment: I don't really know much about writing node.js servers, so there could be problems with that part that I can't see.